# const applied to "universal reference" parameter

Tags: c++, reference, constants, universal-reference

I've stumbled upon Scott Mayers article on universal references, [link](https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers).

From what I understood universal reference, that is some type `T&&` can mean an rvalue or lvalue type in different contexts.

For example:

```
template<typename T>
void f(T&& param);               // deduced parameter type ⇒ type deduction;
                                 // && ≡ universal reference
```

In the above example depending on template parameter the `T&&` can be either an lvalue or rvalue, that is, it depends on how we call `f`

```
int x = 10;
f(x); // T&& is lvalue (reference)
f(10); // T&& is rvalue
```

However according to Scott, if we apply `const` to to above example the type `T&&` is always an rvalue:

```
template<typename T>
void f(const T&& param);               // “&&” means rvalue reference
```

Quote from the article:

> Even the simple addition of a const qualifier is enough to disable the
>   interpretation of “&&” as a universal reference:

**Question:**
Why does `const` make an "universal" reference rvalue?

I think this is impossible because following code makes confusion then:

```
template<typename T>
void f(const T&& param);               // “&&” means rvalue reference

int x = 10;
f(x); // T&& is lvalue (reference) // how does 'x' suddenly become an rvalue because of const?
f(10); // T&& is rvalue // OK
```

Comment: What is the question? Are you asking for 'language-lawyer' justification of where this rule is specified in the standard, rationale for this behaviour, or an explanation for why your compiler doesn't exhibit the behaviour that Scott Meyers describes?

Comment: What's the question? The code is [ill-formed](https://ideone.com/osnNtR), just as the language rules say. `x` does not "suddenly become" anything.

Comment: @Mankarse Not sure what you mean by 'behavior', I just want to understand how does `const` affect universal references. as shown in examples above.

Comment: @codekiddy: I mean the 'behaviour' of 'failing to compile the code sample/failing to accept lvalue arguments to template function taking `(T const &&param)`'. `const` affects universal references in the way the Scott Meyers describes: it disables them.

Comment: @Mankarse, Oh, yes, I see now. I didn't compile the sample code at all. that makes sense now.

Comment: For anyone in the future reading this, this might explain: http://www.codesynthesis.com/~boris/blog/2012/07/24/const-rvalue-references/

Comment: @codekiddy: The article is a bit too dismissive. Const rvalue references can be useful for controlling overload sets, e.g. as for [`as_const`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/as_const).