# Does 'const' disqualify universal reference?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I have a human class with ctor using universal reference

```
class Human {
 public:
  template<typename T>
  explicit Human(T&& rhs) {
    // do some initialization work
  }

  Human(const Human& rhs);  // the default ctor I don't care about
}
```

Now if I have a const Human object

```
const Human one_I_do_not_care; // then play with that
Human the_human_I_care(one_I_do_not_care)  // now create another one
```

Does the last line use the template ctor or the default ctor? My understanding is the "const" will disqualify the template ctor, am I correct?

```
Human the_human_I_care(one_I_do_not_care)  // line in question
```

By const disqualify the template ctor, I mean adding const then it would not match the template ctor, not it still matches two but compiler picks one.

Comment: What's preventing you from adding a few debugging statements, and figuring it out on your own?

Comment: I did, what I got is different than what's mentioned in the book

Comment: If I tell the compiler to use the move constructor, it works.  `Human the_human_I_care{std::move(one_I_do_not_care)};`

Comment: @Eljay how come? one_I_do_not_care is const, how could you move it? I think you still just do a copy

Comment: @WhatABeautifulWorld • std::move performs a cast to a universal reference.

Comment: @Eljay I know, I mean after you cast you still do a copy. But this has nothing to do with my question. I just want to know if the *const* makes the template ctor not qualified.

Comment: @WhatABeautifulWorld • Once you have a `Human const&&` from the std::move, that universal reference will work in the explicit constructor as a `T&&` where T is `Human const`.

Comment: @Eljay got it, thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Does the last line use the template ctor or the default ctor? My understanding is the `const` will disqualify the template ctor, am I correct?

No. You are passing a **`const`**-qualified `Human` as an argument. Since both constructors would *match equally well* (i.e.: if the template would be instantiated to take a `const Human&`), then the *non-template* constructor is preferred over the template (and no template instantiation for a `const Human&` parameter ever occur).

Comment: I did try to test it out. I think what you said is half correct: 1) Adding a const does pick the default ctor; 2) marking the default ctor *delete* makes it not be able to find a ctor, which means it's wrong to say "the template would be instantiated to take a const Human&".

Comment: @WhatABeautifulWorld by *would be instantiated* I mean it is **not** instantiated: instantiation does not happen.

Comment: @水飲み鳥  "both constructors match equally well " this is not correct. The template ctor will not match after adding const. Please revise your answer and I will upvote :)

Comment: @WhatABeautifulWorld It should be "both ctors **would** match equally well*

Comment: @水飲み鳥  I tested on my local machine, it seems if I mark the default ctor *delete*, the compiler could not find a ctor. If both match equally well, it would find the template ctor, right? That's all the question is about and the part I want to know.

Comment: @WhatABeautifulWorld if you delete the default ctor and you've not defined a non-template ctor, then you have no ctor at all.

Comment: But I have the template ctor? I am confused?

Comment: @WhatABeautifulWorld, no, deleted constructors still participate in overload resolution.

Comment: @WhatABeautifulWorld Deleting things aren't missing.  They follow usual overload resolution rules.  If they are selected, an error occurs.  This is *different* than them not being there.

Comment: @WhatABeautifulWorld the way to get the template "ctor" called is by kind of "playing" with the process overloading resolution: you must have at least one non-template ctor, so that it matches worse than the template ctor. That way the template ctor is elected.

Comment: Thanks all! To summaries, T&& could still bind to const, const doesn't disqualify that. Seems hard to digest because of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34556808/const-applied-to-universal-reference-parameter

Comment: Oh, @水飲み鳥 btw, your answer should be "No". My question is: does the const DISQUALIFY the template ctor or not. From the discussion above, it doesn't disqualify that.